# Creating Url.Action causes URL string to build incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a button which has an onclick function of `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SendRegisterLink?Email="+ item.Email, "Account")'"`

The button works, the URL builds, and I have some JS which grabs the "Email" field from the URL fine - but I am not getting the correct output:

**EXPECTED URL**

```
/Account/SendRegisterLink?Email=test@test.com
```

**ACTUAL URL**

```
/Account/SendRegisterLink%3fEmail%3dtest%40test.com
```

Comment: if you use `Url.Action` you need to provide only the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the actual parameters of the functions. You can use ctrl + click in the latest vs to check its params.

```
public static string Action(this IUrlHelper helper, string action, string controller, object values);
```

If you want to use the `Action` function you can use that overload. The first parameter needs to be only your action name as a string name. So you can use it like this:

```
@Url.Action("SendRegisterLink", "Account", new { item.Email })
```

If you want to mention a URL with the parameters directly, you can use the `Content` function:

```
@Url.Content("~/Account/SendRegisterLink?Email=" + item.Email)
```

If your intention is just a redirect you can also something clean with an a tag:

```
<a href="~/Account/SendRegisterLink?Email=@item.Email">My Link</a>
```

You can always change the css of anchor tags.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Ended up going with the `@Url.Content` method, as it gave me the correct output. The `Url.Action` method still gave me the `test%40test.com` result.

Comment: lol my third example didn't show up. just fixed it. but the `Content` function is quite handy too

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
@Url.Action("SendRegisterLink, "Account", new { Email= item.Email});
```

Comment: In the latest version of c# the `Email =` isn't really required. The key is implied as `Email` from `item.Email`